# What will be the output of program - switch case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int main() {
    int i = 1 ;
    switch( i==2) { /* This line */
        case  0: printf("zero "); break;
        case  1: printf("one "); break;
        case  2: printf("two "); break;
        default: printf ("what?"); break;
   }
}
```

What will be the output? I can't understand the expression in the switch parentheses.

Comment: Runt it and see what it prints and then analyse why it is?

Comment: Read about boolena/logical expressions in C.

Comment: Try it:  http://ideone.com/IwUIZf

Comment: What did you think the `==2` was going to do in the switch statement?  Was the original intent simply to switch on the value of `i`?

Comment: BTW: You declared `main` to return an `int`, but there is no `return` statement in your code.  I recommend ending with `return 0;`

Comment: @abelenky `return` in `main` (but not in other functions) is optional. In C99 it will return 0 if you omit it.

Comment: Suppose someone said "I don't understand 'Bob sees Jane.'". Since that's a very basic sentence in English, we would want to know what it is about it that they don't understand. Similarly for "I don't understand 'i==2'". What about it don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

The expression `i==2` evaluates to only `0` or `1` - to `0` (`false`) when `i` is not equal to `2` and to `1` (`true`) when `i` is equal to `2`. The other cases under the switch statement are useless.

In your case, where the value `i` is set to `1`, `i==2` evaluates to `0`. Hence, you should get `zero` as your output.

Comment: To be complete, you should mention that boolean operators such as '==' evaluate to 0 when false and 1 when true.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a boolean expression in switch case `i==2` will always result either in `1`(True) or `0`(False). There wasn't any need of using `case 2:` and `default:` statement.

Now when executing switch expression `i==2` will jump to `case 0` since `i=1` and you are checking whether it is equal to 2.

Hence will result in false, 0 in case of C programming. And finally printing

> Zero